How do I use a latent variable stigma to predict another latent variable depression using R lavaan
I am trying to use a measurement model with stigma as the factor that is measured by 12 items to predict depression which is measured by 20 items. I am thinking of structuring this as one latent predicting another latent, but I am not sure about 1) what is the advantage of doing it this way compared to regressing the total score of depression on latent stigma, 2) how to model it in lavaan. Here is what I have and
library(lavaan)
model="
stigma=~hss_1+hss_2+hss_3+hss_5+hss_7+hss_8+hss_12+hss_14+hss_15+hss_16+hss_17+hss_24

depression=~cesd_12m_1+cesd_12m_2+cesd_12m_3+cesd_12m_4+cesd_12m_5+cesd_12m_6+cesd_12m_7+cesd_12m_8+cesd_12m_9+cesd_12m_10+cesd_12m_11+cesd_12m_12+cesd_12m_13+cesd_12m_14+cesd_12m_15+cesd_12m_16+cesd_12m_17+cesd_12m_18+cesd_12m_19+cesd_12m_20

depression ~ stigma
"
fit <- sem(model, data = dat, missing = "ML")
summary (fit)

This didn't work because there was not enough variation in depression.

You might get better answers if you added the appropriate language/framework tag.  I have no idea what language this is.
